# How can I delete an app in eventbrite's web interface?

Tags: eventbrite

In https://www.eventbrite.com/account-settings/apps, how can I delete an app?
[image: Screenshot from eventbrite app management page, no delete link]

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the platform for this kind of question. However, It is under Key Details > Scroll down to the bottom of the page.